# Найти k-ую цифру в последовтельности

Tags: python

Задача: Дано натуральное число k. Составить программу получения k-той цифры последовательности:

```
а) 110100100010000..., в которой вписаны подряд степени 10

б) 123456789101112..., в которой вписаны подряд все натуральные числа

в) 149162536...,в которой вписаны квадраты всех натуральных чисел

д) 01123581321..., в которой записаны подряд все числа Фибоначчи
```

Прошлый вопрос удалил, самому делать не лень было. Забыл добавить код

```
def task1():
    num1 = 110100100010000
    num2 = 123456789101112
    num3 = 149162536

    num_arr = []
    
    while num1 > 0:
        num_arr.append(num1 % 10)
        num1 //= 10
    
    k = int(input("Enter index of the digit: "))
    
    for i in range(len(str(num1))):
        if i == k-1:
            result = num_arr[i]

    print(f"Result: {result}")
```

Проблема в переменной **result**. Если ее объявить как `result = 0`, тогда результат выдает 0, какой бы индекс я не вписал, однако если ее не объявить вообще, то выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\eclipse_workspace\Lab05\Lab05\t2.py", line 34, in <module>
    task1()
  File "D:\eclipse_workspace\Lab05\Lab05\t2.py", line 23, in task1
    print(f"Result: {result}")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задание выглядит сложно-запутанным и код усложнен. Получить k-ю цифру можно с использованием среза в одной строке

```
num1 = 110100100010000
k = int(input("Enter index of the digit: ")) # индексы в списках начинаются с 0
print(str(num1)[k:k+1])
```

```
Enter index of the digit: 0
1
```

Comment: а если попросить 1000 знак последовательности? вы видимо не поняли суть задания.

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev очевидно, что не понял, о чем и написал. Код не порождает новых последовательностей, используются константы. Вы поняли задание?

Comment: Константы используются просто для нахождения индексов, не указал в задании. Создать последовательность не так трудно, проблема в нахождении индекса была

Comment: встречал такие задачи - весь смысл в том, что они неограниченные и например можно потребовать найти 10**100 знак такой последовательности - если вы попробуете сгенерировать такое число и перевести его в строку, то у вас это займет слишком много времени, а может даже и памяти. Такие задачи делаются по другому - там находится какое число стоит в данной позиции, затем уже цифра числа, иногда таких этапов гораздо больше (ну например задача когда записано `1234567891011121314...` и надо найти k-ую цифру - приходится вычислять какое число на этой k-ой цифре, том какая цифра числа на k-ой цифре)

Comment: @Zhihar если это не олимпиада, то врядли. Но если надо, тоже можно. для каждого списка запоминать последнее вычисленное число и позицию, тоже пока не превысим k

Comment: ну не олимпиада конечно, но codewars задачи 4-5 уровней, опять же - если чисел много (да хотя бы даже миллиард) то уже слишком большие вычисления

Answer (score 3):

Собираем в список и ждем, когда длина всех элементов превысит k.

Обратите внимание, что в функции, вычисляющей числа Фибоначчи, счет элементов идет не с 1, как принято, а  с нуля

```
def fibonachi(i):
    a0 = a1 = 1
    for k in range(2, i+1):
        a0, a1 = a1, a0 + a1
    return a1


def task1():
    k = int(input("Enter index of the digit: "))

    num_arr = ['' for _ in range(4)]
    i = 0
    while any(len(x) < k for x in num_arr):
        num_arr[0] += str(10**i)
        num_arr[1] += str(i+1)
        num_arr[2] += str((i+1)**2)
        num_arr[3] += str(fibonachi(i))
        i += 1
    print(*[num_arr[i][k-1] for i in range(len(num_arr))])

task1()
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы не привели ограничения. А они могут быть очень большими. Например, найти десятимиллиардную цифру первой последовательности. Тут уже простым накоплением строки не справишься, она будет слишком длинной. Придётся голову включать.

Нетрудно заметить, что длина первой последовательности зависит от количества вписанных в неё степеней как 1,3,6,10,15... - это т.н. треугольные числа, суммы арифметической прогрессии 1+2+3+4+... (ведь длины степеней десятки именно такие), и они могут быть выражены как

```
T(n) = n * (n+1) / 2
```

А единицы в этой последовательности идут на местах T(n)+1 (1,2,4,7,11,16...)

Так что **задачу можно решить за несколько операций**, не тратя память и время - для позиции `p` возьмём `d=p-1`  и решим квадратное уравнение

```
d = n * (n+1) / 2
n^2 + n - 2*d = 0
```

Если корень целый, то результат - единица, иначе ноль (нужно учитывать погрешности вычислений, например, при получении n=5.999999987 понятно, что это 6).

(А корень целый, если дискриминант `D=1+8d` является квадратом нечётного числа)

Остальные задачи решаются аналогично, разве что уравнения будут посложнее, и для Фибоначчи не всё сходу понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вы слишком намудрили в своей программе. Можно сделать гораздо проще:

```py
num = 110100100010000
num = str(num)
k = int(input("Index: "))
if k <= len(num):
    print(num[k - 1])
else:
    print("Index is too big")
```

Ну а вообще в вашем способе есть 2 ошибки.

1. После цикла `while` нужно перевернуть массив цифр

```py
num_arr = num_arr[::-1]
```

2. Этот `for` выглядит максимально странно:

```py
for i in range(len(str(num1))):
    if i == k-1:
        result = num_arr[i]
```

Замените его на `if`

```py
if k <= len(num_arr):
    result = num_arr[k - 1]
```

Но вообще в задаче требуется работать с неограниченными индексами как я понимаю. Можно сделать так:

```py
def get_next_digit():  # Для последовательности 110100...
    a, ind = 1, 1
    while True:
        for i in str(a):
            yield i, ind
            ind += 1
        a *= 10


k = int(input("Index: "))
for a, ind in get_next_digit():
    if ind == k:
        print(a)
        exit()
```

Comment: т.е. если  надо будет найти какой-нибудь 100500900-й знак вы будете возводить в неизвестно какую степень неизвестно сколько раз и потом переводить в строку, опять же неизвестно сколько раз? (что займет неизвестно сколько памяти и времени)

Comment: @Эникейщик Именно так) Это не самое производительное решение. Но это что-то среднее между простотой кода и производительностью, и его легко адаптировать под любую последовательность чисел.